# creating Qlabels with dynamic name at run time

Tags: python, qlabel

```
#in this example len(list) is 5

i=0
while i < len(list):
    label=q_label_i                 #creating a name for the label
    self.label=QLabel()             #
    grid.addWidget(self.label,i ,0)     # grid is a grid = QGridLayout()
    i=i+1
```

the above code creates 5 labels however they are all called q_label_i and not q_label_0 q_label_1 .... q_label_4

In another function - I am going to read data from a file and update these labels and will refer them as q_label_0 q_label_1 .... q_label_4

any tips on how to get this to work will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **two** names you have to deal with.  The variable name the qlabel is bound to and the `objectName` that `Qt` uses.

When dealing with a variable number of items, it's usually best to store those in a dictionary or list

```
self.labels = dict()
for i in range(5):
    name = 'q_label_{}'.format(i)
    label = QLabel()
    label.setObjectName(name)
    grid.addWidget(label, i, 0)
    self.labels[name] = label
```

Later on, when you want to reference the label, just do

```
self.labels['q_label_2']
```